# Is there any way in RoR to add some optional parameters in route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a route here:

```
get  'api/users/:id/friends/:fid', to: 'friends#show'
```

I want to make the `:fid` as optional parameter. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the code as below:

```
get  'api/users/:id/friends(/:fid)', to: 'friends#show'
```

Answer (score 6):

just put it in parenthesis

```
get  'api/users/:id/friends(/:fid)', to: 'friends#show'
```

more information in guideline (paragraph 3.1)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: tip for Stackoverflow: append 4 blank spaces before each line of your code to make appear in a colored form